# Change Permission of root site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online

"I am unable to break permission for site collection. i am facing below exception "Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot change permissions of root web:https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/PowershellTestingSite"

```
$webURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/PowershellTestingSite"
$adminUrl = "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com"
$userName = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$members = "i:0#.f|membership|SecureUser@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
# Let the user fill in their password in the PowerShell window
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "tenantpassword" -AsPlainText -Force


$SPOCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName, $password)

# Creating client context object
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webURL)
$context.credentials = $SPOCredentials
$web = $context.web
$context.load($web)

$web.breakroleinheritance($false, $false)
$web.update()

#send the request containing all operations to the server
try
{
    $context.executeQuery()
    write-host "info: Broken inheritance for $($web.title)" -foregroundcolor green
}
catch
{
    write-host "info: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red
}
```

Comment: You can not break role inheritance on the rootweb of a sitecollection. Only on subsites or lists. Why would you want to break role inheritance on the root? Break from what?